# Angular ssr css variables name change issue

Tags: css, angular

Suddenly some of my css variable names on SSR build on server are being changed to something else and not working.
For example i have

```
.color-black-75 {
    color: var(--black-75-color);
}
```

in my styles.css but when i build project on server in browser it turns to:

[image]

i checked out to older commits from 1 month and 2 month ago but this is still happening.

everything works fine when i build project on local ( with docker ) but on server this is preventing some css classes from working.

Comment: it seems it is Angular issue. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42170

Comment: @Andrei As i understood that issue is about setting css variable from an Angular service but this issue is about variable names being changed on SSR build.

Comment: I believe that the root cause is the same. engine is not up to date, to support css variables

Comment: could you try to set ViewIncapsulation.None? it could save from code transformations in some situations, but you will loose the incapsulation thing. also you could try to put this code in the global styles

Comment: @Andrei That way each components style will affect other components HTML and we will have bigger problems. I didn't update angular version or anything all of the versions are declared static in Dockerfile and Package.json and this project is live from 3 years ago. I don't think the problem is ViewIncapsulation but thanks anyway.

Comment: @BehnamAminazad did u find the root cause ?

Comment: @ManuJanardhanan I did post an answer below, i found out the root cause was a package update because i was using ^ and ~ for specifying versions in package.json i didn't try to find the exact package but i solved it by replacing all ^ and ~ so all of the versions were exact version and copied package-lock.json from my local which all versions were fine on it to server.

Comment: @BehnamAminazad Alright. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find and replace corrupted classes in *.css with correct classes in dist folder so the project will work fine on server until we find the real issue.

Then if project is being built fine on your local then the issue should be about Package.json package versions or your Dockerfile installed application versions so you can copy your local package-lock.json file to server via scp and then push your local docker image and then pull on server so these issues would be fixed.

The real issue in this case was a package version update which you could find with comparing local package-lock.json with server package-lock.json and then removing ^version and ~versions from package.json and use exact version so over time your packages won't be updated and won't cause any issue.